# Android subpixel rendering

Tags: android, android-canvas, subpixel

I have a line that should get thinner the longer it gets. The problem is, that you can clearly see a jump when it gets a pixel thinner. Is there a way to do subpixel rendering/antialiasing on Android?

`canvas.drawRect()` takes float values, but it's ignoring those. Here's the code:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    float width = getMeasuredWidth() / (float) getMeasuredHeight()  * getMinimumHeight();
    float left = (getMeasuredWidth() - width) / 2.0f;
    canvas.drawRect(left, 0, left + width, getMeasuredHeight(), paint);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

The paint object has `ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG` enabled and contains a solid color.

This is the default line:

[image: Default line]

This is when it gets longer and thinner. It should have some anti aliasing on the sides, though to make the whole transition seems smoother.

[image: Thinner line]

Comment: Have you tried `setAntiAlias( true )`? It's easy to accidentally override a flag using `setFlags()`.

Comment: No, it's not working either. I'm not setting any other flags :/

Comment: Could you post a screenshot?

Comment: I've edited my post and added screenshots, thanks!

Comment: Actually drawLine with the strokeWidth set seems to do the job!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to do a better job:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    float width = getMeasuredWidth() / (float) getMeasuredHeight()  * getMinimumHeight();
    float left = (getMeasuredWidth() - width) / 2.0f;
    paint.setStrokeWidth(width * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
    canvas.drawLine(left, 0, left, getMeasuredHeight(), paint);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```